# Proof using the converse.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For all Y⊆N, if Y is finite then Y complement (A^c) is infinite
Prove this question using the converse method and decide whether this statement is true or false.

My method-
Was to show that the intersection of A and A complement is the empty set, but I don’t think that shows if they’re finite or not.

Comment: Do you mean *contrapositive* instead of converse?  There is no recognized principle of proof using the converse.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by the "converse method".  The "converse" of the statement "if p then q" is "if q then p" but the truth of one tells us nothing about the truth of the other!  Perhaps you are referring to the "contrapositive".  The contrapositive of "if p then q" is "if NOT q then NOT p".  In this problem the statement is "If Y is finite then the complement of Y is infinite" (Y a subset of N).  The contrapositive is "if the complement of Y is NOT infinite then Y is NOT finite" which is the same as "if  the complement of Y is finite then Y is infinite."

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using proof by contradiction, which I assume is meant by proof using the converse.

Assume there exists some finite $Y \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ so that $Y^c$ is also finite.

We know that the union of two finite sets is another finite set, so $Y \cup Y^c$ is finite, we also know by the definition of the complement that $Y \cup Y^c = \mathbb{N}$ which has to be infinite, since $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite. This is a contradiction!

Because assuming there exists a finite set $Y \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ so that $Y^c$ is also finite leads to contradictions which must mean that that assumption is false, meaning that there either exist no finite sets that are subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ - obviously wrong since $\{1\}$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ - or for all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ the property holds that if the subset is finite, the complement of the subset is infinite.

As a remark, depending on who is asking you to prove this and in what context, you might not be allowed to state that the union of two finite sets is finite or that the union of a set and its complement in $\mathbb{N}$ are equal to $\mathbb{N}$ or you might even be required to prove that $\mathbb{N}$ is itself infinite at all, or possibly they might want you to prove that it really is a contradiction for a set to be both finite and infinite.